# My code is running smoothly, but showing no out put?

Tags: java

Project name is ectnt:

```
package ectnt;

import java.sql.*;

public class db {
    Connection con;
    Statement st;
    ResultSet rs;

    public db() {
        connect();
    }

    public void connect() {
        try {
            String driver = "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver";
            Class.forName(driver);
            String db = "jdbc.odbc.Databn";
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(db);
            st = con.createStatement();
            String sql = "select * from table2";
            rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
            while(rs.next()) {
                String fname = rs.getString("Fname");
                String lname = rs.getString("Lname");
                String age = rs.getString("Age");
                System.out.println(fname+" "+lname+" "+age);
            }
        } catch(Exception ex) {
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new db();
        //new gui();
    }
}
```

My this code is running smoothly but showing no output, any one have any idea?

Comment: Your query come up empty. Or there is an exception and you don't care about that.

Answer (score 0):

On a quick look i'd say that it fails somewhere in your code, but your catch-block is empty. So when something somewhere in your try fails, then nothing is executed as your catch won't do anything.

Have your exception do something like ex.printStackTrace()

EDIT: something like below:

```
public void connect() {

        String driver = "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver";

    try {
        Class.forName(driver);
        String db = "jdbc.odbc.Databn";
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(db);
        st = con.createStatement();
        String sql = "select * from table2";
        rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
        while(rs.next()) {
            String fname = rs.getString("Fname");
            String lname = rs.getString("Lname");
            String age = rs.getString("Age");
            System.out.println(fname+" "+lname+" "+age);
        }
    } catch(Exception ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Double-check your DB-name and table might also be a good start, you'll get that information once you read the stack trace or post it here